# Runtime error in VBScript

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have two Excels as an input. I am taking values from one excel and passing it as a parameter to other excel for applying filter. Once the filter is on, I am reading filtered values from a column and trying to match a condition as mentioned in the below code. And everything working fine up to this place. Once I get the specific match, I have to write it back to first Excel but I am getting runtime error while doing so.

```
strPath = "C:\Users\PSingh\Desktop\CodeInventory.xlsx"
strPath1 = "C:\Users\PSingh\Desktop\MyScripts\Processes.xlsx"

Dim rows

Set objExcel1 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel1.Visible = True

Set objExcel2 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel2.Visible = True

Set objDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
 objDict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

Const xlUp = -4162
Const xlCellTypeVisible = 12

Dim a(), val

objExcel1.Workbooks.Open(strPath1)

With objExcel1.Activeworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
  rowcount = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  MsgBox rowcount
End With

Redim Preserve a(rowcount)

For i=1 To rowcount
  a(i) = objExcel1.Activeworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i,1).Value
  objDict(a(i)) = a(i)
  'msgbox a(i)
Next

n = objDict.Items

objExcel2.Workbooks.Open(strPath)

For i=0 To UBound(n)
  With objExcel2.Activeworkbook.Sheets("All")
    .Range("A1").AutoFilter 19, "="&n(i)
    'rows=.usedrange.columns(1).specialcells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    For Each cl In objExcel2.Activeworkbook.Sheets("All").UsedRange.Columns(12).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
      If (InStr(cl, "Seq") <> 0 Or InStr(cl,"seq")) <> 0 Then
        objExcel1.Activeworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i,2) = "Data" 'Not Working
        Exit For
      End If
    Next
  End With
Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with,

```
objExcel1.Activeworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, 2) = "Data"
```

You loop with `i` begins at `For i = 0 to ...`. There is no row zero in column B.